# Gradient Boosting vs Random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, xgboost

According to my understanding, RF selects features randomly and hence is  hard to overfit. But, in sklearn Gradient boosting also offers the option of max_features which can help to prevent overfitting. So, why would anyone use Random forest? 
Can anyone explain when to use Gradient boosting vs Random forest based on the given data?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit like saying "cars drive down roads, but boats go fast in the water.  Why would anybody use a boat to go down a road?"  Of course random forests has certain types of data problems for which it is well suited.  It's a supervised learning method which is good when you have many features and want to allow each one to potentially play a role in a model without worrying about bias.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the difference is though that it is easy to recognize when to use a boat and when to use a car. It is not always as clear when to use random forests vs when to use gradient boosting. There are several sophisticated gradient boosting libraries out there (lightgbm, xgboost and catboost) that will probably outperform random forests for most types of problems. Identifying problem characteristics that indicate when a random forest might perform better is a good question imo. I certainly don't have an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to [machine learning, rather than software development](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

According to my personal experience, Random Forest could be a better choice when..

1. You train a model on small data set.
2. Your data set has few features to learn.
3. Your data set has low Y flag count or you try to predict a situation that has low chance to occur or rarely occurs.

In these situations, Gradient Boosting algorithms like XGBoost and Light GBM can overfit (though their parameters are tuned) while simple algorithms like Random Forest or even Logistic Regression may perform better. To illustrate, for XGboost and Ligh GBM, ROC AUC from test set may be higher in comparison with Random Forest but shows too high difference with ROC AUC from train set.

Despite the sharp prediction form Gradient Boosting algorithms, in some cases, Random Forest take advantage of model stability from begging methodology (selecting randomly) and outperform XGBoost and Light GBM. However, Gradient Boosting algorithms perform better in general situations.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked on Quora:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-random-forests-and-boosted-decision-trees-compare

I agree with the author at the link that random forests are more robust -- they don't require much problem-specific tuning to get good results.  Besides that, a couple other items based on my own experience:

- Random forests can perform better on small data sets; gradient boosted trees are data hungry
- Random forests are easier to explain and understand.  This perhaps seems silly but can lead to better adoption of a model if needed to be used by less technical people

Comment: I don't think that random forests are easier to explain or understand, at least for the final model. The training process is a bit easier but the final model for both is the same, a (weighted) sum of decision trees.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's also true. I have also read on this page [How Random Forest Works](https://medium.com/@Synced/how-random-forest-algorithm-works-in-machine-learning-3c0fe15b6674)
There explains the advantages of random forest. like this :

1. For applications in classification problems, Random Forest algorithm
   will avoid the overfitting problem
2. For both classification and
   regression task, the same random forest algorithm can be used
3. The Random Forest algorithm can be used for identifying the most
   important features from the training dataset, in other words,
   feature engineering.